# rbenv exec bundle exec instead of just bundle exec

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I'm trying to set up rbenv:

https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#section_2

I have this working with one problem: I have to use `rbenv exec` before everything

So now to do bundle exec I do:

rbenv exec bundle exec

How do I get around this?

**Edit**

After running rbenv rehash I get:

```
$ ➔ rbenv rehash
$ ➔ rails s

bash: /usr/local/bin/rails: /usr/local/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Doesn't rbenv have something like `rvm use 1.9.3` that sets ruby 1.9.3 as a current ruby?

Comment: @mipadi read the update. doesn't help :(

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes rbenv is an alternative to rvm, instead you do rbenv local 1.9.3

Comment: What's your $PATH look like? Seems like it's trying to load a non-rbenv ruby/rails installed under /usr/local/bin rather than your stuff stored under $HOME/.rbenv.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Silly really:

I forgot to run `exec $SHELL` so my PATH was not updated. Initially the strings:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

were put into .bash_profile, but should have been in .bashrc. After fixing this I forgot to reopen/run the above command!

Thanks to @Dylan Markov in the comments for pointing me in the right direction :)